# setFile method not called using FormFile[] while uploading multiple documents in Struts 1 and Tomcat 8

Tags: forms, file, jsp, tomcat8, struts1

We are facing issues while using the following snippet with struts 1 and Tomcat 8 but in struts 1 with Tomcat 6 it's working fine.

### ActionForm code:

```
public class FileUploadForm extends ActionForm

private FormFile file;

public void setFile(int index, FormFile file)
//putting the file in a map
}

public FormFile getFile() {
return file;
}
}
```

### In struts config

```
<form-bean name="fileUploadForm" type="com.actionform.FileUploadForm"/>

<action path="/Upload"
type="org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingActionProxy"
name="fileUploadForm"
scope="request"
validate="true"
input="/multiplefileupload.jsp">
<forward name="success"/>
```

### JSP

```
<input type="file" name="file[0]"/>
<input type="file" name="file[1]"/>
```

I didn't get any exception when trying the code with Tomcat 8 and Struts1 but the ActionForm setter method setFile(int index, FormFile file) method is not getting called here.
This happened when we try to migrate the struts 1 code in Tomcat 8.
Thanks in Advance. Please let us know your suggessions on this.

Note: This code works fine in Tomcat 6 and Struts1.